# pep8 has no option to force same indentation in whole code

Tags: python, pep8

pep8 assumes that this is a **correct** style:

```
if True:
        print 'yes'
else:
    print 'no'
```

http://pep8online.com/s/0VqA3PVj

I can not find any error or warning option that make it incorrect. That's too bad to accept such that code.

Am I wrong? Is there an option? If not, why?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible ways to have inconsistent indentation:

1. Mix tabs and spaces
2. Different levels of indentation using spaces

For the first the PEP-8 checker will complain about the use of tabs, (unless you have that turned off).

```
so.py:3:1: W191 indentation contains tabs
so.py:5:1: W191 indentation contains tabs
```

One option is to run `pylint` rather than just the PEP-8 checker on its own - it will, (with default settings), complain about the tab indentation:

```
W:  3, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:  5, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
C:  1, 0: Missing module docstring (missing-docstring)
```

and for the second case complains:

```
W:  3, 0: Bad indentation. Found 8 spaces, expected 4 (bad-indentation)
C:  1, 0: Missing module docstring (missing-docstring)
```

As you can see [pylint](http://www.pylint.org) does check more than just PEP-8 compliance.

There are lots of online checkers such as [this](http://antares.sip.ucm.es/cesar/pylint/) or you can install `pylint` locally with:

```
pip install pylint
```

Answer (score 1):

PEP 8 says "use 4 spaces per indentation level".  The code above does not do that (it uses difference sizes for the two indentation levels), so it's not conforming to PEP 8.

Comment: The problem is exactly that pep8 **accept** it without any error and warning. Test it please.

Comment: @iman: PEP8 is a document.  What you linked to is a website that someone made.  Like many programs, it may have bugs.  According to PEP8 the code isn't valid, but that doesn't mean every program that everyone writes to check it will catch this error case.

Comment: @BrenBran please test it with your pep8 checker on your system and let me know. Here is my test: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12095392/

Comment: @iman: What I'm saying is that no PEP8 checker is the same as PEP8.  These PEP8 checkers are just programs written by people who have to manually add each PEP8 condition.  Just because people wrote a program that says your program conforms to PEP8 doesn't mean it actually conforms to PEP8.

Comment: @BrenBran Yes, I know PEP8 is a document not a tool but my question is about *an aoption for pep8*. Anyone knows that a document has't option. I mean pep8 tool: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8

Comment: @iman: If your question is "Can I get this `pep8` tool to find this error", the answer is no.  If your question is, "Is this code in violation of PEP8," the answer is yes.  If your question is about a command line tool, you should make that clear, because when people see "pep8", they'll probably assume you're talking about PEP 8, not a program called pep8.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry your question appears to have been downvoted heavily -- I was annoyed by this behavior as well recently. To answer your actual question:

> Am I wrong [that there is no way to have pep8 complain about inconsistent indentation levels]? Is there an option? If not, why?

No, you're not wrong, and no, there's no option. Why not? Sure seems like a bug / missing feature to me. I opened an [issue](https://github.com/PyCQA/pep8/issues/430) on the Project's tracker, let's see if it goes anywhere.

**Edit**: I took a look at the pep8 code to see how difficult fixing this gripe would be. You can check out this [issue-430 branch](https://github.com/schmiddy/pep8/tree/issue-430) for the initial fix, which should give you an error E117 for the example you posted. I think a little more work is needed to allow tabs-only code to pass this check, so I haven't opened a Pull Request upstream just yet.